# Microsoft Edge: SCRIPT0: SCRIPT0: 'FormData' is not defined

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

I have one XMLHttpRequest in javascript which is posting the FormData object to server. This call works fine in Chrome. On Microsoft Edge, I am seeing this error: "SCRIPT0: SCRIPT0: 'FormData' is not defined".

Here is my snippet:

```
function saveRecording(recordingData, endpoint, token) {

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
    randomNumber = randomNumber.toString().slice(0, 4);
    var recordingName = "Recording " + randomNumber;

    var sender = {
        sliceNumber: 1,
        sliceMaxSize: 1024 * 1024,
        sliceStart: 0,
        sliceEnd: 1024 * 1024,
        total: recordingData.blob.size,
        recordlength: recordingData.length.toFixed(2),
        fileName: '',
        sendSlice: function () {
            if (this.total > 0) {
                var slice = undefined;

                if (this.total >= this.sliceMaxSize) {
                    this.sliceEnd = this.sliceStart + this.sliceMaxSize;
                }
                else {
                    this.sliceEnd = this.sliceStart + this.total;
                }
                slice = recordingData.blob.slice(this.sliceStart, this.sliceEnd);

                var isLastSlice = !((this.total - this.sliceMaxSize) > 0);
                console.log(slice);
                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("data", slice);
                formData.append("sliceMaxSize", this.sliceMaxSize);
                formData.append("sliceNumber", this.sliceNumber);
                formData.append("fileName", this.fileName);
                formData.append("dictation", JSON.stringify(recordingData.dictation));
                formData.append("isLastSlice", isLastSlice);
                formData.append("length", this.recordlength);
                formData.append("encoding", recordingData.encoding);
                formData.append("name", recordingName);

                //var params = 'data=ipsum&sliceMaxSize=binny&sliceMaxSize=binny&sliceMaxSize=binny&sliceMaxSize=binny&sliceMaxSize=binny&sliceMaxSize=binny';

                var sender_this = this;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    //readyState=4 means request finished and response is ready
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {
                            //Success 
                            sender_this.fileName = JSON.parse(this.response).fileName;
                            sender_this.sliceNumber++;
                            sender_this.sliceStart = sender_this.sliceStart + sender_this.sliceMaxSize;
                            sender_this.total = sender_this.total - sender_this.sliceMaxSize;

                            // send the next slice
                            sender_this.sendSlice();
                        }
                        else {
                            //Fail
                            self.postMessage({ command: "saveRecordingFail", message: JSON.parse(this.response) });
                        }
                    }
                };
                request.open("POST", endpoint, true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
                //request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.setRequestHeader(token.name, token.value);
                request.send(formData);

            }
            else {
                //recording completely sent to server, post message to worker caller
                self.postMessage({ command: "saveRecordingSuccess" });
            }
        }
    };

    // send the slice
    sender.sendSlice();
}
```

**Workaround already tried:**

I have already checked that FormData works in edge by manually trying on the edge console which created the FormData object successfully.

[FormData working fine in console of edge browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b796X.png)

Comment: Is the browser running as IE9?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=FormData

Comment: @epascarello it is running as IE11 and as already mentioned in the post FormData works fine in console but while in the actual code it gives this error

Comment: @LakhteyHussnain Could you find a reason or a solution for this issue? I'm experiencing the same with FormData in Edge in a Web Worker although it's working fine in Chrome, Safari, or FF.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to make a test with sample code below and find that it is working fine with MS Edge browser (user agent string: IE 11)

```html
<!doctype html>
<script>
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

// List key/value pairs
for(let [name, value] of formData) {
  alert(`${name} = ${value}`);  
}
</script>
</html>
```

I suggest you to check all the values that you are trying to append and verify that all are having proper and correct values.

I suggest you to check all the values one by one to find the problematic value.

It may help to narrow down the issue. Than it will be easier for you to fix the issue.

Reference:

[FormData](https://javascript.info/formdata)